# how to retain the strings in sed 's/(.*)/?/g', ? is what?

Tags: shell, sed

the string is  ">ABCD EFG;" . i want to change `>, ,;,` to `_,;,!` by shell command "sed", how to do ?

i try,
`echo  ">ABCD EFG;" |sed 's#>(.*) (.*);$#_$1;$2!#g'`
and the result is `>ABCD EFG;`
$1 and $2 are errors?
unuseful!

Comment: The flavour of regex used by sed defaults to [POSIX BRE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03). You appear to want to use [POSIX ERE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04); some versions support using this by specifying the `-E` option. sed [extends this](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_02) slightly. Replacement syntax uses "\" not "$" - see [`s` command description](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_03)

Comment: Your example does not contain `>, ,;,`; I don't think we can guess what you want or what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sed use basic regular expression (BRE) by default. That mean you need to escape some character.

This `>(.*) (.*);$` regular expression would work using extended regular expression (ERE, `-E`), but would look like `>\(.*\) \(.*\);$` using BRE.

Secondly the replacement syntax uses `\` and not `$` (from sed's man page) :

> The  replacement  may contain the special character & to refer to that portion of the pattern space which matched, and the special escapes \1 through \9 to  refer  to  the corresponding matching sub-expressions in the regexp.

So your sed command using BRE should look like (note that the command `g` isn't mandatory, as in your example you need to do this modification once per line) :

```
sed 's/>\(.*\) \(.*\);$/_\1;\2!/'
```

Answer (score 0):

> i want to change >, ,;,to _,;,!

Why not use `tr`, e.g.:

```
<<<">ABCD EFG;" tr '> ;' '_;!'
```

Output:

```
_ABCD;EFG!
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use `sed`, you can choose between commands like

```
# Use \1 en \2 to paste remembered strings
echo ">ABCD EFG;"|  sed -E 's/>(.*) (.*);/_\1;\2!/'

# Replace characters anywhere in the string
# Since you are replacing in 3 steps, replace the ' ' at the end.
echo ">ABCD EFG;"|  sed -E 's/>/_/g; s/;/!/g; s/ /;/g'

# Special y operator
echo ">ABCD EFG;"|  sed 'y/> ;/_;!/'
```

You don't often see the 'y' operator in `sed`, because the `tr` command does an excellent job. @Thor showed that in his answer, where `<<<">ABCD EFG;"` is an efficient way of writing `echo ">ABCD EFG;"|`.